# Best practices to use Fog::Logger

Tags: fog, fog-aws, fog-google

What are the best practices to use Fog::Logger. Fog provides 3 types of logging:

1. debug
2. deprecation
3. warning

   ```
   module Fog
     class Logger
       @channels = {
         :deprecation  => ::STDERR,
         :warning      => ::STDERR
       }

       @channels[:debug] = ::STDERR if ENV["DEBUG"]

       def self.[](channel)
         @channels[channel]
       end

       def self.[]=(channel, value)
         @channels[channel] = value
       end

       def self.debug(message)
         write(:debug, "[light_black][fog][DEBUG] #{message}[/]\n")
       end

       def self.deprecation(message)
         write(:deprecation, "[yellow][fog][DEPRECATION] #{message}[/]\n")
       end

       def self.warning(message)
         write(:warning, "[yellow][fog][WARNING] #{message}[/]\n")
       end

       def self.write(key, value)
         channel = @channels[key]
         if channel
           message = if channel.tty?
                       value.gsub(Fog::Formatador::PARSE_REGEX) { "\e[#{Fog::Formatador::STYLES[$1.to_sym]}m" }.gsub(Fog::Formatador::INDENT_REGEX, "")
                     else
                       value.gsub(Fog::Formatador::PARSE_REGEX, "").gsub(Fog::Formatador::INDENT_REGEX, "")
                     end
           channel.write(message)
         end
         nil
       end
     end
   end
   ```

   If we use debug logging then it is only visible when debug mode is on. 
   What is the best way to use it, please give some examples if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logger is intended for messages from fog to end users, rather than for direct use from end-users. I would suggest the levels would be used something like this:

1. debug - Not really used much, more for usage during development than something I would expect to be used for messaging to end-users.
2. deprecation - Any time we have changed a behavior, but left a backwards-compatible adapter we try also to have a deprecation warning explaining and hopefully driving users to update.
3. warning - This makes sense for anything related to usage that the user should be made aware of in addition to what is happening (ie if something changed on the provider side or the provider returns a warning, but it isn't broken enough to actually raise an error).

Hope that helps, but certainly happy to discuss further as needed.